# Fundamental Theorem of Galois theory question

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic number and $p$ a prime. Show that there exist field extensions of finite degree $\mathbb{Q} \subset F \subset K$ such that $\alpha \in K$, the degree $[K:F]$ is a power of $p$, and $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$ is prime to $p$.

Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, let $n$ be its degree.

If $gcd(n,p)=1$, then we can take $F= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $K= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt[p]{2}) $. Then we are done.

Otherwise, let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ and $L$ be $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, we have that $Gal (\frac{K}{\mathbb{Q}})$ is a group, say order $p^l m $. By Sylow's theorem, we have that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $Gal (\frac{K}{\mathbb{Q}})$ of order $p^l$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, we know $H$ corresponds to some group $F$. So we have $[F:\mathbb{Q}]= \frac{p^l m}{p^l}=m $, and $[K:F]= p^l$.

Thus, we are done.

Could someone please check if my proof makes sense? Also, I'm wondering that is it really necessary to have 2 cases for when $gcd(n,p)=1$ and $gcd(n,p)>1$? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems entirely fine as far as I can see.

I do think that there is no need for two cases. The only thing that happens if $p\nmid n$ is that the Sylow-$p$ subgroup becomes trivial, and that $[K:F]=1=p^0$. I personally think that qualifies as a power of $p$. Ultimately, though, that's up to whoever gave you the exercise.